# Publishing layer (shapefile or postgis) with TileMill moves it 200 meters?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, leaflet, tilemill

I am working with the TileMill application to publish layers.

Well, first I have posted directly loading the shp file., But when the charge goes I moved about 200 meters.

Then as I have the option, I imported the layer from postgis and my surprise was that the movement was more than 1000 km.

After choosing SRS: Custom and put the appropriate reference system, the movement returned to be 200 meters.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include your custom CRS in the question, and into which direction the offset goes.

Comment: SRS: "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs",  displacement is north

Answer (score 4):

An offset of 200m looks likely to be a false datum shift.

The WGS84 definition for UTM 30N is: `+proj=utm +zone=30 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

The ED50 definition for UTM 30N looks very similar:

```
+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

but has a shift of about 200m to the WGS84 coordinates.

So I suggest to add the +towgs84 parameters to your custom definition.